Could Senator Bernie Sanders be in a better position than the Administration to be informed regarding Israeli-Palestinian relations?
Senator Sanders is Jewish, which is to say that anything regarding the Israel and Palestine situation affects him directly. So here are the main variations of my question:

If the Democrats pursued policy X and made Bernie Sanders its spokesperson, would he make it more acceptable than a non-Jewish spokesperson?

Given that  Bernie Sanders is positioned as both a) A Jew and b) a "dove" is he regarded as a fair and reasonably impartial designer of Israeli-Palestine policy?


Put another way, is Bernie Sanders someone President Biden could regard as a reliable adviser whose guidance would be worth considering on this critical matter?

In my opinion, from the Israel relations PoV.  I would say no.  Look at how Schumer's, who is also Jewish, and a lifelong supporter of Israel, speech was received (yes, yes, it was also a bit out there with the call for elections, I'll grant you that).  From the Palestinian relations PoV, it is unlikely Sander's being Jewish would make any policies more palatable (than they would otherwise be).  Fixing this problem won't be decided by US showmanship it will be decided by actual compromise by Palestinians and Israelis, which is unlikely to happen very soon.

"reasonably impartial designer" Bernie Sanders is probably not that impartial or representative for Democrats.

Sen. Chuck Schumer is Jewish too. Bernie is more of a lefty, so the Dems would have to be in pretty desperate trouble to bring him in as a surrogate. I don't think that's the case at all, since from a D-vs-R point of view, the party leaders don't differ substantially on Israel policy. There is confidence they can ride out the storm of public concern until the Gazans are dead and forgotten.

How does Bernie Sanders being Jewish (something he downplays) make the Israel and Palestine situation affect him directly? The Palestinians  aren't shooting  missiles at his house in Vermont. They don't blow up any buses that he rides on. They aren't going on stabbing sprees anywhere he shops. Etc.

Generally speaking, no and no.
Sanders might be a Jewish descendant, but his stances against Israel are long-lived. In 2016 Sanders supporters lauded his pro-Palestinian stance

"You gave a major speech to AIPAC, which obviously deals with the
Middle East crisis, and you barely mentioned the Palestinians,"
Sanders scolded.
"There comes a time when, if we pursue justice and peace, we are going
to have to say that Netanyahu is not right all of the time," he
asserted, to applause from the audience.

He reiterated that stance in 2019

“At a time when we spend $3.8 billion on military aid to Israel, we have the right to say to the Israeli government that the United States of America and our taxpayers and our people believe in human rights, we believe in democracy, we will not accept authoritarianism or racism and we demand that the Israeli government sit down with the Palestinian people and negotiate an agreement that works for all parties,” Sanders said at a Washington conference hosted by J Street, a liberal advocacy group whose stated mission is to help end the Arab-Israeli and Israeli-Palestinian conflicts.

He tried again by trying to place conditions on Israeli aid in Jan 2024

US senators have defeated a measure, introduced by Bernie Sanders, that would have made military aid to Israel conditional on whether the Israeli government is violating human rights and international accords in its devastating war in Gaza.

Sanders has called the war in Gaza immoral, called Benjamin Netanyahu a racist, and accused Israel of trying to starve the Palestinians as well. US Israeli supporters refute the starvation accusation directly.
Sanders message may be unwavering, but it does not seem like it is aimed at building any sort of consensus within the Democratic party, let alone with the people of Israel.

I think the OP's premise may be that Sanders's anti-Netanyahu message won't be viewed as anti-Semitic or anti-Israel because he's Jewish.

During the 2016 presidential campaign Sanders made a gaffe, which merited the mentioning in Wikipedia, when he claimed that 10,000 Palestinians were killed in 2014 Gaza war:

“Anybody help me out here, because I don’t remember the figures, but my recollection is over 10,000 innocent people were killed in Gaza. Does that sound right?” he said first.
Told that the number was “probably high,” Sanders responded: “I don’t have it in my number… but I think it’s over 10,000. My understanding is that a whole lot of apartment houses were leveled,” he went on. “Hospitals, I think, were bombed. So yeah, I do believe and I don’t think I’m alone in believing that Israel’s force was more indiscriminate than it should have been.”
[...]
According to Palestinian figures cited by the UN Human Rights Council, 1,462 civilians were killed out of a total of the 2,251 Gaza fatalities during the 51-day conflict. Israel, for its part, has said that up to half of those killed on the Palestinian side were combatants, and has blamed the civilian death toll on Hamas for deliberating placing rocket launches, tunnels and other military installations among civilians. Seventy-three people were killed on the Israeli side of the conflict.

In the follow-up it transpired that Sanders generally had poor grasp of the facts related to Israel, as he didn't know who was Michael Oren (the outgoing Israeli Ambassador to the US at the time, who accused Sanders of blood libel). This latter gaffe was not unlike the What is Aleppo? which was the end of Gary Johnson candidacy.


Senator Sanders is Jewish, which is to say that anything regarding the Israel and Palestine situation affects him directly.

How does Bernie Sanders being Jewish (something he downplays) make the Israel and Palestine situation affect him directly? The Palestinians aren't trying to capture Vermont. They aren't  shooting missiles at any of his three houses. They don't blow up any buses that he rides on. They aren't going on stabbing sprees anywhere he shops. Etc

If the Democrats pursued policy X and made Bernie Sanders its spokesperson, would he make it more acceptable than a non-Jewish spokesperson

Given Bernie Sanders long term hostility towards Israel the Democrats would be a lot better off with a non-Jewish spokesman who is perceived as neutral

Given that Bernie Sanders is positioned as both a) A Jew and b) a "dove" is he regarded as a fair and reasonably impartial designer of Israeli-Palestine policy

I haven't seen anyone writing about the conflict  , regardless of what their personal view is  who perceives Bernie Sanders as an impartial voice about   it. He is universally viewed as anti-Israel.
Putting Bernie Sanders in this position would elicit far more sentiment  and comments and from a lot more people that is  similar to that of  Democratic  congressman Jared Moskowitz who    tweeted last week  :  "Bernie, now do AntiSemitism. Why so quiet?"
